# Pass different versions of variable through asynchronous callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I'm having trouble with some asynchronous database queries.  I'm using the Async library for Node.js.  I have some code forming an object before it hits the add() function.  In my code, I have a loop the executes to create the object multiple times.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
    var obj.id = i + '_idstring';
    add(obj);
}
```

As you can see, each object is slight different.  I need to perform a lookup in my database to see if the object already exists (1st waterfall function) and if it does not, add it to my database (2nd waterfall function).  My issue is, loaObj.id always equals 10_idstring.  Is this a problem with how I'm passing the object through the callbacks?  How should I be handling this?

```
function add(loaObj) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(loaObj, callback) {
            var sql = "";
            connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
                callback(error, results, loaObj);
            });
        },
        function(results, loaObj, callback) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                sendMessage();
            } else {
                var sql = "";
                connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
                    callback(error, loaObj);
                });
            }
        }
    ], function(err, loaObj) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
            sendMessage();
        } else {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet isn't valid JS because object properties like `obj.id` can't be declared with keywords like `var` or `let`. You should be able to just do something like `add({ id : i + '_idstring' })` though

Comment: Your loop is changing the same object, and `loadObj` is going to refer to that same object. You should be creating a new object in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using Object, which will be passed by "copy of a reference", then `obj.id` will be overridden with every loop and it will settle down to `10_idstring` -where the loop stops-.
One simple solution is to pass new Object every time like below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
  add({id: `${i}_idstring`});
}
```